# Accepted Answer, later modified (content strikethrough by owner), and Pointed out to another answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488355/if-exists-then-select-else-insert-and-then-select/1488386#1488386) where OP accepted answer, but later on, answer modified by owner (content strike-through by owner), and just pointing out to another answer of the same question.

What I need to do in this situation?

Is I need to mark this as "not an answer"? or flag it or just simple "Skip it"?or notify to MODs?

Comment: Why do you need to do anything at all?

Comment: The answerer updated their outdated answer to reflect that it was outdated, and instead of copying information, they were kind enough to point to an exisitng correct answer. Nothing wrong here. In fact, it's good they updated to point out the information was incorrect. Not everyone does that.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the title of the question :-)

Comment: @Bill Woodger :- I did not noticed that...:-), but yes it weird

Comment: @Kyralessa:- just want to put on board so that we can discuss what is SO want to do in this situation where it just pointing out to another..and its itself has no value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer ceases to be of value.  There's no reason to have an answer that just says, "go read this other answer".  It should be deleted.

Sadly, the OP has accepted the answer, so the author couldn't delete it even if he wanted to (presumably this is why he merely linked to the other answer instead of deleting it before now).  Only a mod can delete the post at this point, so you should flag the post for moderation attention, state that the author has recognized that the answer isn't correct but cannot delete it due to it being accepted.

Comment: @Servy- Agreed ...thats why I put this discussion on board here..

Comment: Having a bad solution pointed out as obviously bad could have some value I think.

Comment: @TZHX The *good* answer explains what will happen if you do it wrong, which is exactly the right way to do this.  Rather than having an answer saying, "do this" with a disclaimer somewhere saying, "oh by the way, this is bad", it's far superior to have a *good* solution with an explanation for why it should be done that way instead of other bad ways.  It provides all of the same valuable information without the pitfalls of having a post that just has a bad answer.

Answer (score -6):

**Do nothing**

//I think its a small honor to such a respectful answerer

Many times, striking through the wrong answer has much significance.
Its not always saying what is correct. Its also about pointing out what is wrong.

Comment: may not be all cases..  Assume an answer was updated because the previous doesn't hold good for new framework.. like deprecated property or such

Comment: @SunilBN The answer was just wrong.  It had significant but hard to diagnose or recognize bugs right from the start.   There is nobody that is going to be better off using that over the other answer.